# How I can get a text between <option></option>?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Good day. I have a code `<option value="63">1963</option>`

How can I get "1963" then to display on the page?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**

```
var selectTag = document.getElementById("yourIdForSelect");
selectTag.onchange = function(){
     var selectedValue = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text; //returns 1963 when you select this option
     // selectedValue contains the 1963
};
```

Comment: and how I can put 1963 into variable?

Comment: please have a look udated answer `selectedValue` contains that value.

Comment: thanks. to call I should plain write selectedValue();?

Comment: The variable `selectedValue` should used without parenthesis `()`, only by `selectedValue`.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
$('#lol').change(function(e){
  var my_val = $(this).val();

  if( my_val == "65" ) {
    alert( $(this).find(':selected').text() );
  }
});
```

live demo here http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/P3NNR/

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
 <select id="select">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    </select>
```

**jquery**

```
$('#select option:selected').html();
```

OR

**html**

```
<option value="63" class="select">1963</option>
```

**jquery**

```
$('.select').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following js code to get the text of an option in select box

Js code

```
var text=$('#selectboxId').find('option[value=63]').text();
alert(text);
```

Answer (score -1):

http://api.jquery.com/val/ there is a demo (first example) that does exactly what you are looking for.

html:

```
<select id="single">
    <option>Single</option>
    <option>Single2</option>
</select>
```

jquery (js):

```
var singleValues = $( "#single" ).val();
```